# Pie Mutation test fails : org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.EmptyObjectReturnValsMutator

Tags: java, spring-boot, tdd, mutation-testing

While running mutation test , there are survived cases . The reason is org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.EmptyObjectReturnValsMutator

The exact error message is :  replaced return value with Collections.emptyList for package/JavaFile::Method → SURVIVED

I added few test cases to pass the emptyList but still failed.Can anyone please help here about this and what's the test case need to be added?

Comment: Include a test case that verifies that the return value is not equal to `Collections.emptyList()`. That mutation will make it fail, therefore effectively killing the mutant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typical case for a method which returns Set.

Example:
private Set execute() {
}

This set is always with value (or) empty set.

The call to this method 'return execute()' showed the issue of replaced return value with Collections.emptyList for package/JavaFile::Method → SURVIVED.

The logic is changed like 'return Optional.of(execute())'

This solved the issue.